# Bringing out a constant out of continous composite function

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be continuous functions where $f,g: R \to R$ and let $h(x) = (f o g) = f(2g(x))$ where $h: R\to R$, can I assert $f(2g(x)) = 2f(g(x)) = h(x,y)$? Is there a theorem that allows me to do this (bring the constant out of the composite function)? I think there is one, but I can't recall it for some reason.

Comment: In general this is not true. Take for example $f(y)=1$ for all $y$. This is something you have to assume.

Answer (score 0):

No we can't do that in general, for example

- $g(x)=x$
- $f(x)=x^2$

then

$$f(2g(x))=4x^2 \neq 2f(g(x))=2x^2$$

Comment: are there specific instances when we can?

Comment: We need that $f(x)$ is linear that is $fx)=cx$.